# Hover effect cannot be applied to previous by using selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**Issue description:**

I want to make the class `.first`and class `.third` visible after `:hover` over class `.second` by using the `display: unset` css command. Actuall issue is, that I can change the display of the element implemented **after** (`.third`) the class `.second`  and not the element implemented **before** (`.first`). I tried every me known selector for the classes that should affect onto the `hover` (`+` *and* `~` *and* `space`);

**Code**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
.second {  
  background: blue;
}
.third {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.second:hover + .first {
  display: flex;
}
.second:hover + .third{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
  <div class="third">Third</div>
</div>
```

**Further information:** I know it's possible to solve this by getting the value class via JavaScript and edit the style properties. This is not what i want. I want a pure CSS solution.

*Thank's for your help*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using the general sibling selector `~` and the `order` property.
Note that I've put the second element first in the HTML.

But, that makes a crazy behaviour, as your first element appears on the position of the second element on hover…

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first {
  background: red;
  order: 1; /* TAKIT: Added this */
  display: none;
}
.second {  
  background: blue;
  order: 2; /* TAKIT: Added this */
}
.third {
  background: red;
  order: 3; /* TAKIT: Added this */
  display: none;
}

/* TAKIT: Changed the below */

.second:hover ~ div{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="second">Second</div><!-- TAKIT: Changed order here -->
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="third">Third</div>
</div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Maybe you want to do something like this instead:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first {
  background: #f88;
  order: 1;
  display: none;
}
.second {  
  background: #88f;
  order: 2;
}
.third {
  background: #f88;
  order: 3;
  display: none;
}

.second:hover ~ div {
  display: flex;
}

/* TAKIT: Added the below */

body {
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}

.container div {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .first:hover, .container .third:hover {
  display: flex;
  background: #8f8;
}
```

```html
<p>(Try to hover from the center)</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="second">Second</div>
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="third">Third</div>
</div>
```

Doc about `order`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting previous sibling elements is currently not possible via CSS so the easiest way *to make the class* `.firstand` *and class* `.third` *visible after :hover over class* `.second` is to utilise :hover on the parent element (in this case `.container`).

The user experience is almost the same, only difference being :hover staying true if you move your cursor over to `.third` or `.first`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
.second {  
  background: blue;
}
.third {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.container:hover .first,
.container:hover .third {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
  <div class="third">Third</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am unsure wich answer to set as correct because of the fact your both answers work pretty fine. Only issue with your solution is that in case I have something like an input and I want to change the hover into a focus the container option would not work. 
So for the sake of more flexible solution I have to choose those with the order property in css. Thanks anyway for your quick answer.